# Which LEGO set did these small tan, grey and tan bricks come from?

Tags: set-identification, advanced-models

Can anyone help me identify this LEGO set?

I just opened the bag and those are all the pieces, I don't know how to build or how to find instructions.

[image: Large pile of bricks, mostly 1x1 and SNOT]

[image: Original bag the bricks came in]

[image]

Comment: Please explain more about what you know about these pieces and why you think they are a set.

Comment: Its from a big box and i took this bag and opened it so it has to form a set

Comment: My guess is that they are just *part* of a set, and there may be one or more additional bags that — together — make up a complete set. Unfortunately, I’m not sure which set.

Comment: It looks like there is a good answer here.  Maybe the OP will accept it eventually?

Comment: @chicks - When I posted my first question here, without creating an account, I couldn't find any way to select the appropriate answer given.  Is there a way?  If not it is something that I feel needs a solution.  I think most questions without a chosen answer are probably because of this problem.

Answer (score 9):

Those are mostly fairly generic pieces, however the 4x8 in Medium Blue only appears in 7 sets, and of those only Tower Bridge has any 1x8 in Reddish Brown.

This is part of  [10214-1: Tower Bridge](https://brickset.com/sets/10214-1/Tower-Bridge)

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find instructions for them and I've been looking for them the entire day can you help me with a link?

Comment: You can find instructions on the Brickset page, under the set image

Comment: @TalalMDabak, you can also find manuals on the Lego manuals page: https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions. Search for the set number above: 10214.